# How can we connect an frontend react application with another application running on tomcat server for backend accessibility on production?

Tags: reactjs, tomcat

How can we connect an frontend react application with another application running on tomcat server for backend accessibility on production?

We have created an react app for frontend and our backend code is deployed on tomcat server.

On devlopment mode, we are able to access backend code from react application using proxy. But when we are trying to deploy the same on production, we are getting 404 error.

It will be helpfull if somebody can guide us with the deployment process.

Comment: did you build whole app after deploy?

Comment: the application on tomcat is deployed separately by creating an war and the react app is deployed separately by generating build folder by executing command "run build". and then build folder is deployed using nginx

Comment: This is surely do to configuration issue only, please check CORS configuration in both servers and fix it

Comment: can you guide us regarding cors configuration.